# Wire Validator to run on specific button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I'm building a user control which has 2 buttons in it.

This is my html:

```
<form action="#">
<div id="container" runat="server" style="text-align: center;">
    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="+" Style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px"
        OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="test" runat="server"/>
</form>
```

And in the code side I'm adding some new text boxes according to the user's clicking on the addBtn:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //clear the session values
        ViewState[VIEWSTATE_NAME] = null;
        ViewState[VIEWSTATE_TEXT_BOX_LIST] = null;
        return;
    }
    Debug.Write("here");
    //if there is no text box list in the session - create a new one
    if (ViewState[VIEWSTATE_TEXT_BOX_LIST] != null)
        textboxIds = (List<string>)ViewState[VIEWSTATE_TEXT_BOX_LIST];
    //get the name of the list
    if (ViewState[VIEWSTATE_NAME] != null)
        Name = (string)ViewState[VIEWSTATE_NAME];
}

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    //if there is no name - return
    if (name == null)
        return;
    //add a new text field to the list                
    textboxIds.Add(name + "_" + (textboxIds.Count + 1));
    //st text field id         
    //add the textbox list to the session
    ViewState[VIEWSTATE_TEXT_BOX_LIST] = textboxIds;
    //show the fields
    ShowTextFields();
}

/// <summary>
/// Show all the text fields of this multiple text fields
/// </summary>
private void ShowTextFields()
{
    Debug.Write("count" + textboxIds.Count);
    foreach (string textBoxId in textboxIds)
    {
        //create textbox
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        //create validator
        RequiredFieldValidator validator = new RequiredFieldValidator();
        //add textbox
        textBox.ID = textBoxId;
        container.Controls.Add(textBox);
        container.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        //add validator
        validator.ControlToValidate = textBox.ID;            
        validator.ErrorMessage = "Required";
        container.Controls.Add(validator);        
    }
    container.Controls.Remove(btnAdd);
    container.Controls.Add(btnAdd);
}
```

Each of the added text boxes are required - there for I've added a validator to each on of them.

My problem is that the validator is running in the addBtn click, while I want it to run on the form submit button on click...

How can I wire it to happen ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ValidationGroup` to determine what validates what and what triggers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

If you want the addBtn to not validate anything, you can add `CausesValidation=false` to the button.